# Request for self destructing comments

Tags: support, app-request, comments, script-request

#### What would I like?

I would like comments that can self destruct after a set amount of time.

#### Why?

I often add a comment that doesn't need to stay around, like saying thanks to a user, or telling them I edited according to their suggestion.

#### How?

A button above the "help" would be nice. I guess it would take the userID of the person who added it, ask for a time (days / hours) and then register that (local storage?) then each hour run a check and delete any comments to be removed at that time.

I have no idea how to program this, however. I'd be interested if this can be done. I'm also interested in learning, so if someone does make it, I'd like to be able to look at the code, and maybe some simple explanation of how it works. Of course I don't need that and you guys here are volunteers, and busy.

#### Inspiration

[I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256108/252153) about there being a "instant delete" word, whereby someone can flag it and it's instantly removed - in the same way a comment can be insta removed if it contains the words "accept rate". However, [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256162/252153) there could be a self destruct, to achieve the same thing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a userscript to do this.

Get it at [Github](http://shu8.github.io/SE-Comment-Self-Destruct/).

It will add a button next to comments that belong to you *after* you have posted them (so not as you're writing). Clicking it will produce a prompt asking you for the number of days in which to delete the comment.

Eg. entering `2` will delete it in exactly 2 days.

It checks every o'clock for times that have passed - anything that has passed will be deleted.

It might be buggy, but it's worked for me... so far :)

To use it, you'll need an access key, which you can get from [here](http://shu8.github.io/SE-Comment-Self-Destruct/). Please copy and paste the key in the prompt which you can access by going to your profile and clicking `self-destruct access-token` next to the 'network profile' link at the top. You'll also need Greasemonkey, or Tampermonkey to use it, as the script relies on `GM_*` functions.

This is completely client side, so, if you say 'delete in 2 days' and don't use your computer for 3 days - it will only delete at the next o'clock your computer is on for.

[image]

I've made a proper post [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/6316/self-destructing-comments).